# Getting Fonts to work in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, font-awesome

I don't know what's wrong. It seems like I'm doing this right. I'm trying to use [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#integration) in my application but the font doesn't appear. I have a folder called `fonts` and in my `application.rb` included the line:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
 # Enable the asset pipeline
 config.assets.enabled = true
 # This line
 config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

and than instead of having the 2 css files that come with Font-Awesome (**CHANGED SEE BELOW**) ( didn't need the IE7 one) I just put the main css inside of my `application.css`. Than I change the urls to detect the font files.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot') %>');
  src: url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.woff') %>') format('woff'), 
  url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.ttf') %>') format('truetype'), 
  url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome') %>') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I turned off the server and restarted after each change to the code but still no good. What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

I'm not using SASS or LESS. Maybe the `@font-face` is the issue? I never seen this type of code use before.

**UPDATE**

I'm now using the font-awesome.css file. But its not showing up in my source code.

```
<head>
  <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="/assets/chosen.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
  <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/chosen.jquery.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

**FULL ANSWER**

This is how you can get it Font-Awesome working with inserting it normally.

**QUOTE** from: https://gist.github.com/2251151

```
1. Download font-awesome from https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome

2. Put the font folder font folder in the app/assets. I renamed the folder from font to fonts to make it clearer

3. Add config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts" to config/application.rb. This is to include the apps/assets/fonts folder in the asset pipeline

4. Put the font-awesome.css file in the app/assets/stylesheets folder

5. The first part of the css should be:

@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('fontawesome-webfont.svgz#FontAwesomeRegular') format('svg'), 
         url('fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesomeRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

You should then be able to use:

<div style="font-size: 24px;">
  <i class="icon-camera-retro"></i> icon-camera-retro
</div>
```

Comment: please provide a sample of the entire application.css file

Comment: You need to add **.erb** extension to parse the eruby parts in your CSS file. no need for .scss though. Also, you can always go to /assets/application.css and see how Rails outputs your CSS data

Comment: `*= font-awesome` is wrong, I think. As a test, remove that and add `*= require_tree` just before the closing `*/`. See if it helps.

Comment: I am always weary about doing a `require_tree .`from an application.css file as most times you will want to be more specific about the load order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really need to put that code into a css.scss file then include it in the application.css (you will need the css.scss to use the asset_paths)

UPDATE: You will need to change your `*= font-awesome` to `*= require font-awesome` and also rename `font-awesome.css` to `font-awesome.css.scss`

Comment: So I have to use SCSS? I can't use the regular `css` file? Also, I deleted all the the Font-Awesome files to restart and now am using the `font-awesome.css` normal file but notice not that when I include it inside of my `application.css` with the `*= require_self` it doesn't show in my pages Source Code. i.e. Its undetected, this is the only file that does this.

Comment: OK, so far so good but the last thing is I don't understand this error I'm getting now: `Invalid CSS after "...awesome-webfont": expected ")", was ".eot') %>');"`